# My bot doesnt send me an private message what did i do wrong?

Tags: discord

```
client.once('ready', async () => {

    console.log('Bot Ready');

    client.channels.cache.get(projektratID).send(`Bot Eingeschalten`)
   // client.users.cache.get(userId).send(`Server wurde wieder eingeschalten`);
     const user = await client.users.fetch(userid);

   user.send('Blabla');
}); //here?
```

Maybe i need to change some options of my bot because I cant send him messages because he is not my friend?